# Форматирование целого числа из "12345678" в "12 345 678"

Tags: java, android, format

Как сделать форматирование числа из "12345678" в "12 345 678". То есть нужно каждую 1000 отделить пробелом, что бы большие числа выглядели эстетично.

Comment: Форматирование для хранения? Для вывода?

Comment: @Jenssen для вывода

Answer (score 8):

Попробуйте так:

```
NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getInstance();
int i = 12345678;
System.out.println(f.format(i)); // 12 345 678
```

P.S. Как здесь справедливо заметили, итоговый результат будет зависеть от текущей локали. Для того, чтобы не зависело, нужно указать конкретную локаль:

```
NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("ru", "RU"));
```

Список локалей и представления чисел в этих локалях можно посмотреть [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html)

Comment: Результат будет зависеть от активной локали пользователя. Может получится и `12,345,678`, как один из вариантов. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html

Comment: Да откуда вы все CANADA_FRENCH взяли?

Comment: @PavelMayorov чем плоха канадская локаль?)

Comment: Данный метод разбил запятыми, но потом я запятые заменил пробелами, так что все получилось. Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Ещё один способ, без создания лишних объектов:

```
String.format(Locale.CANADA_FRENCH, "%,d", 1234567890);
```

Результат

> 1 234 567 890

Answer (score 0):

Решение независящее от локали:

```
DecimalFormat formatter=new DecimalFormat();
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols=DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' '); //явно задаем символ разделителя тысяч
formatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
int i=12345678;
String s=formatter.format(i).toString(); //12 345 678
```

P.S. можно написать более красиво через конструктор `DecimalFormat` с паттерном задающим символы локализации `DecimalFormatSymbols` - специально привел в длинном виде, чтобы была понятна логика.